# How can I search for a specific fiddle in my JSFiddle?

Tags: jsfiddle

I really like [`JSFiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/), and I used it a lot.

At this moment, I have about 80 fiddles that I **created/forked** in [`my JSFiddle dashboard`](https://jsfiddle.net/user/bheng/fiddles/). I have to go through 8 pages to look for a **specific** fiddle using my eyes to scan through each title.

[image]

---

I might be doable since I only have 80 fiddles, but what if I have 500 or 2000 fiddles by next year ? That will take me forever to scan though each title with my eyes. I'm seeking a better way to deal with this.

Is there a way to search for a specific fiddle without having to go through all the pagination and scan through each title ?

Any tips on that will be much appreciated.

Comment: I just wrote this for that. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/jsfiddle-search/ Indexes your jsfiddles and adds a search box to the left top of the "All your fiddles" dashboard It will only index fiddles on the "All your fiddles" pages that you've visited It wont crawl the pages, you will have to click though them yourself

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as you so I've created a fiddle to search in my list of fiddles :)

http://jsfiddle.net/panzerkunst/77fgau53/show/

It uses the JSFiddle API to get back your list of fiddles

```
$.ajax(
        {
            url: "http://jsfiddle.net/api/user/"+this.username+"/demo/list.json",
            data: {
                limit:this.limit
            },
            dataType: "JSONP",
            jsonp: "jsoncallback",
            type: "GET"
        }
    )
    .done(this.dataReceived.bind(this))
    .fail(this.errorHappened.bind(this))
    .always(this.resetControls.bind(this));
```

and then the list is filtered based on the keyword you provide.

```
dataReceived: function(data){
    var query = this.query;
    var filtered = _.filter(data.list, function(item){if(item.title.contains(query) || item.description.contains(query)){ return item}});

    [...]
}
```

Hope this helps !

Nicolas

**UPDATE**: to make it work with *your* fiddles, you have to change the username passed to the .initialize() method. http://jsfiddle.net/panzerkunst/77fgau53/

Comment: I tried it out. It doesn't work. It take quite a while. But thanks though for sharing your effort.

Comment: yes, it takes time.. that's because all fiddles have to be retrieved before filtering them (filtering is not foreseen in their API)
have you changed your username when calling the .initialize() method ? 
searchFiddles.initialize({username:"bheng"});
I've tried with your username and that worked

Comment: I should have told you to do that sorry :) The default username is mine ! :)

http://jsfiddle.net/panzerkunst/77fgau53/

Comment: Changed user name but (index):63 Uncaught TypeError: item.title.contains is not a function
    at (index):63
    at VM69 underscore-min.js:5
    at Function.m.each.m.forEach (VM69 underscore-min.js:5)
    at Function.m.filter.m.select (VM69 underscore-min.js:5)
    at Object.dataReceived ((index):63)
    at fire (VM68 jquery-2.1.3.js:3094)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (VM68 jquery-2.1.3.js:3206)
    at done (VM68 jquery-2.1.3.js:8259)
    at HTMLScriptElement.callback (VM68 jquery-2.1.3.js:8689)
    at HTMLScriptElement.dispatch (VM68 jquery-2.1.3.js:4430), 
BUT thanks!

Comment: something must have changed, your fiddle is no longer working iaa, if you could get it working again this would be a very interesting thing to have..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if anyone still ends up here, but I forked Nicolas Bauwens jsfiddle (by panzerkunst) and updated it a bit.

Easily enter any jsfiddle username, then search/filter in either jsfiddle title or text (or leave empty to just show all), and then shows fiddle results in a table with details and clickable links.

https://jsfiddle.net/ElMoonLite/dgfs9aqv/

Should be useable by anyone without the need to install anything.

Core functionality based on:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://jsfiddle.net/api/user/" + this.getUsername() + "/demo/list.json",
            data: {
                limit: 1000
            },
            dataType: "JSONP",
            jsonp: "jsoncallback",
            type: "GET"
        })
```

(and then some string matching for search/filter)

---

More info about the API used:

https://docs.jsfiddle.net/api/displaying-user-fiddles

---

Comment: is it possible to get all public jsfiddles - regardless of author ?

Comment: @provance I doubt you can. The API endpoint has the username in the url and it does not work without a username. If you could get a list of all usernames it might be possible, but I doubt that is possible, and even if you do you have to do a lot of requests (for each user) which will likely get blocked to protect the server.